# manipulating a JSON to correct format in perl

Tags: json, perl

I have a JSON that prints

```
{"d":{"success":true,"drivers":[{"FIRST_NAME":"JOHN","LAST_NAME":"SMITH"},{"FIRST_NAME":"JANE","LAST_NAME":"DOE"}]}}
```

The names change depending on what was found in the database. I need to push this in this format for each result resturned in the JSON:

```
push(@$dummy_data, {'name' => 'testname', 'key' => 'somekey-1234'});
push(@$dummy_data, {'name' => 'testname2', 'key' => 'somekey-5678'});
```

So for this example it would be John Smith in place of testname and Jane for testname2
How would I do this so for each first and last name in the json gets pushed in the format above?

Comment: The data you show is *two* JSON data items. Are you getting this JSON data in individual first name / last name pairs, or is it an array of name pairs? Where do `key` and  `somekey-1234` etc. come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Let's try this new game

```
use strict; use warnings;
use JSON::XS;
use Data::Dumper;

# creating reference to a void ARRAY
my $dummy_data = [];

# creating $json string
my $json = '{"d":{"success":true,"drivers":[{"FIRST_NAME":"JOHN","LAST_NAME":"SMITH"},{"FIRST_NAME":"JANE","LAST_NAME":"DOE"}]}}';

# converting JSON -> Perl data structure
my $perl_hash = decode_json $json;

# feeding $dummy_data ARRAY ref with a HASH
push @$dummy_data, {
    name => $perl_hash->{d}->{drivers}->[0]->{FIRST_NAME},
    key => $perl_hash->{d}->{drivers}->[1]->{FIRST_NAME}
};

# print what we have finally
print Dumper $dummy_data;
```

### Output

```
$VAR1 = [
          {
            'name' => 'JOHN',
            'key' => 'JANE'
          }
        ];
```

Comment: I didnt realize i didnt put the full correct JSON i correct it in the question. I think you are putting me on the right track but after i edited the json and put = to $json i get an error saying Not an ARRAY reference.

Comment: Thank you, I really like this answer! It got me on the right track with out just giving me copy paste code, thanks for helping learn and figure out the rest!